# How do developers find the right libraries/modules/frameworks/APIs that they need for their project?

Tags: resources, prerequisites

Every time I come up with an Idea for a project I can make in Python to advance my skill rather than depend on tutorials, I come across and obstacle; what libraries and other resources would I need to write the software?

I always tried asking google but I give up after realizing that I'm just scrolling to no avail.

How do you guys find exactly what you need in order to your projects?

Comment: Build project ideas off libraries instead of the other way around when you're just starting to learn.

Comment: What was your project idea? If you don't mind me asking

Comment: Multitool with DDoS and RAT etc

Comment: We all have different ways of learning also I don't know how advanced you are with those topics but I would start of watching this (https://youtu.be/1hvVcEhcbLM)

Comment: Then this (https://youtu.be/2nXOxLpeu80)